# Import user certificates to windows 10 trusted root certificates

Tags: ssl, windows-10, vagrant, certificate, homestead

I am generating CRT certificates from `Vagrant` Ubuntu server on a regular basis and I am importing them using windows 10 Manage Certificates tool `mmc.exe.`, currently I am importing them one by one to `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` I am wondering is there a way to:

- import bunch of crt files to `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`
- dynamically do the above process

Thanx for your advice,

Answer (score 0):

I use PowerShell to import CA certificates into the `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` of the computer/machine store.

```
function Add-TrustedRootMachineCertificate($certificate){
  $store = get-item Cert:\LocalMachine\Root;
  $store.Open("MaxAllowed")
  if($store.Certificates.Find(
    "FindByThumbprint", 
     $certificate.Thumbprint, $false).Count -eq 0
  ){
    Write-Host "Add root certificate...";
    $certificate
    $store.Add($certificate);
  }
  $store.Close();
}

$currentDir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent;

foreach($file in Get-ChildItem "$($currentDir)\Root" -Filter "*.cer"){
  $cert = 
    New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(
      $file.FullName);
  Add-TrustedRootMachineCertificate -certificate $cert;
}
```